# IOS Swift TableView Border issues when doing Automated Dimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a TableView that has a column that has variable length as sometimes the text could be long . I fixed that problem by doing the recommended steps such as putting the label lines to 0 and including these 2 lines of code in ViewLoad

```
   TableSource.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    TableSource.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0
```

That fixed the issue but now my border colors are out of whack because of that for instance this is how it looks now [Image below] that behavior occurred when I added those 2 new lines of code above . My guessing that maybe since the cells are auto-resizing depending on the incoming data that the borders are not auto-resizing and they become out of whack . Is there any suggestions on how to fix this ? This is my code to display the borders
**I have 2 images below to compare and contrast**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePageTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomePageTVC



        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(7.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor(hexString: "#8C001A").cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.frame.size.height - width, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width
        cell.layer.addSublayer(border)
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
       return cell
 }
```

[image: With Auto Resizing cells]

if I remove the auto-resizing code basically those 2 new lines then the TableCells look like this. As you can see the borders work now but if a message is too long then it gets truncated .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need put your code to draw your custom draw into your custom cell `layoutSubviews()` method, because is there where the custom cell have the correct calculated width and height this is my code

here is a picture of how looks

[image]

```
import UIKit

class AutoResizedCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblText: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func setupWithText(text:String)
    {
        self.lblText.text = text
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(7.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        border.frame =  self.bounds

        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

and here is my viewController´s code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let arrayOfText = ["asdasddasdadasd asdasd asd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadsdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdadasd asdasdasdasdas dasdasdasd asdas dasdas dasdas dasda sdasd asdas dasdas v ad as v v v v asd as d as s asdasdasdasdada","asdasd","asdasddasdadasd asdasd asd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadsdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdadasd asdasdasdasdas dasdasdasd asdas dasdas dasdas dasda sdasd asdas dasdas v ad as v v v v asd as d as s asdasdasdasdada asdasddasdadasd asdasd asd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadsdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdadasd asdasdasdasdas dasdasdasd asdas dasdas dasdas dasda sdasd asdas dasdas v ad as v v v v asd as d as s asdasdasdasdada","asdasddasdadasd asdasd asd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadsdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdadasd asdasdasdasdas dasdasdasd asdas dasdas dasdas dasda sdasd asdas dasdas v ad as v v v v asd as d as s asdasdasdasdada","asdasdasdasasdas asdasdasd","asdasddasdadasd asdasd asd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadsdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdadasd asdasdasdasdas dasdasdasd asdas dasdas dasdas dasda sdasd asdas dasdas v ad as v v v v asd as d as s asdasdasdasdada","asdasdadas"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.arrayOfText.count
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AutoResizedCellTableViewCell") as! AutoResizedCellTableViewCell

        cell.setupWithText(text: self.arrayOfText[indexPath.row])


        return cell
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you,

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot that code worked exactly how I needed .